# Ramifications of Deleting an Owner on Google Search Console

Tags: google, google-search-console, search

Are there any ramifications to deleting an **owner** inside a property's search console account?

For example:  would the property lose entries made by that owner?

If so, any guidance on how to remove an owner without losing their contributions?

Comment: What contributions have been made?  As far as I know there are very few things in search console that you can set.

Comment: Thank you for the comment/question.

Things like disavow lists or removals, added by the outgoing owner, etc.  

However few the options, I am asking whether those contributions will be deleted with the deletion of the user who added them.